# Can devotees drink "Abhishekam water" of Shiva Lingam?

Tags: shiva, belief, scripture, shiva-lingam

There are [many theories](https://www.colombotelegraph.com/index.php/shiva-lingam-some-scientific-truths/) on Internet that Shiva Lingam (the material by which Lingam is made) is radioactive and continuously water must be poured on it. By citing this, they opine that water is not fit for drinking. They also say 12 Jyotrilingams have high content of Uranium. Anyways, this Scientific speculation is off-topic for this site.

[This blog](http://shivalingapuja.blogspot.in/2011/08/special-thanks-to-capt-js-chauhan-and.html) says

> Never consume anything which has been offered to shiv lingam, it
>   brings bad omen illness, loss of money and luck. But u can have if it
>   is from given specifically by priest as you cannot refuse or from shiv
>   murti or idol.

But [this blog](http://theancientindia.blogspot.in/2013/04/spatika-lingam.html) differs and says we can drink the water.

Are there any scriptures which prohibit devotees from drinking Anointed (Abhishekam) water of Shiva Lingam? If devotees should not drink this water, what are the Spiritual or Religious reasons for this?

Comment: A commonly held belief is that anything that touches the Lingam should not be consumed by devotees.I have found this info on few blogs,don't really know if such instructions are found in scriptures or not.However check the following link,a very reliable webpage for learning the Panchayatana Puja.Scroll down to the bottom where it says -"akAla-mRtyu haraNaM sarva-vyAdhi-nivAraNaM / samasta-pApa-kshayakaraM shrI vishNu-pAdodakaM shubhaM // With this one drinks one sip of the abhisheka water-collection".Now this abhisekha water contains Shiva(Banalinga) abhisekha water too.

Comment: http://www.krishnamurthys.com/profvk/PancAyat.html

Comment: BTW to make the question valid u should add some web sources which say that Shiva nirmalaya which has touched the Shiva Lingam must not be consumed by devotees.However ,in my place,i have seen Shiva temple  having a big bowl of Charanamrit meant for consumption by the devotees.

Comment: @Rickross I never said water must not be consumed. My titles says "Can we drink"? I have seen some temples offering water to devotees.

Comment: If you are asking that can we drink Shiva Linga abhiseka water then u must have seen somewhere where it says that one must not.Otherwise why  the question will arise in ur mind?So you can add some web sources  if u wish.

Comment: For example the following blog claims-"Never consume anything which has been offered to shiv lingam, it brings bad omen illness, loss of money and luck. But u can have if it is from given specifically by priest as you cannot refuse or from shiv murti or idol................Every thing offered on shiv lingam is called nirmalaya. which is forbidden to be consumed or put in any where except in rivers,lakes and sea. Until and unless somebody else offer you by priests. From murti's that is shiv idol you can consume anything.".

Comment: http://shivalingapuja.blogspot.in/2011/08/special-thanks-to-capt-js-chauhan-and.html

Comment: Why not drink the Abhishekam Water? Who says so? Everything that touches Siva Lingam becomes divine. Lord Shiva bestows his blessings in it. Rather it is adharma if you do Abhishekam and don't drink the Teertham i.e. *Abhishekam Water*. Do remember Meerabai, she was served with poison on the name of God she drank it with utter devotion and the poison failed to do the harm to her! Abhishekam Water or Teertham should be consumed is what I think.

Comment: Shiva pooja is done with various objectives. If the pooja is done for dosha nivarana, it is said shiva absorbs the doshas so all negativities are given unto him, that water should not be given as prasadam, but when we pray for healing or world peace we can definitely parttake the prasadam. Bhole nath takes the form that we want and bends to the objective that we pray for.

Comment: I visited to a Lord Shiva temple in my location. In that temple, all the milk and other things used for abhishekam is collected and then devotees can take that to home how much they want.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Answer to your question is - **Yes**, we can drink the Abhisekha water which is also called the "Charanamrit".

There is a [chapter](http://www.kamakoti.org/kamakoti/details/naradapurana12.html) in the Narada Purana which describes the Deva Puja Vidhi,  Matrika Nysasa Vidhi etc in details.

Quoting from the above page:

> Deva Puja vidhi: Maharshi Sanat Kumara then described to Brahmarshi
>   Narada the procedure of worship. Having set up the Puja Region with a
>   Trikona / Chatur kona Mandala with ‘jala prokshana’, a devotee would 
>   recite the Mantras....
>
> He would recite: Om Atma tatwaatmaney namah, Om Vidya tatwaatmaney
>   namah, Shiva tatwa-atmaney namaha; then perform Avaahana (Welcome) of
>   the ‘Ishta Devata’or the Personalised Deity present in the form of a
>   ‘Pratima’ (Idol) or Shalagrama or Linga with ‘Pushpanjali’(flowers) as
>   follows:....

Next, the details of the Shodasaupachara Puja is mentioned which includes Abhisekham  and finally this:

> The Procedure of ‘Visarjana’or ending of Puja is to offer flowers by
>   reciting the Mamtra: Yacchha yacchha param sthaanam Jagadeesha
>   Jaganmaya, Yatra Brahmaadayo Deva jaananticha Sadaashivah/ **Thereafter,
>   the devotee would sip the idol’s ‘Charanaamrita’ saying:**
>
> Akaalamrutyuharanam SarvavVyaadhi vinaashakam, Sarva paapa kshayakaram
>   Vishnu paadodakamm Shubham.

EDIT:

In **MAtrikA Bheda Tantram**, Lord Shiva makes an interesting revelation. He says Shiva Nirmalaya is mokshaprada or giver of liberation. Anyone consuming it will attain moksha. But as a rule a Jiva has to travel through all the 84 lacs of Yonis before getting final liberation. It can not happen anytime before that. That's why Lord Shiva himself preached against the consumption of Shiva nirmalaya in various other Shastras. ( This Tantram says that he preached that in Vedas and Puranas. )

> Sri ChandiKA UvAcha :
>
> AgrAhyam Tava NirmAlyamgrAhyam Karanam Vibho |
>
> MrishA VAkyam MahAdeva Katham Vadasi Yogabhrith ||
>
> ### Meaning
>
> Sri ChandikA Devi said :
>
> [ You yourself have said in other Shastras ] that your nirmalya
>   should not be consumed. Being Yogi how did you utter a lie?
>
> Sri Shankara Uvacha:
>
> Chaturasitilaksheshu Yonigarthe Tathaiva Hi |
>
> Bhramanam Kuruthe Jeevastato Mokshasya BhAjanam ||
>
> Etanmadhye MahA GyAnam Yafi SyAd Veeravandite |
>
> Tada MokkshamvApnoti Bhramanam Kena VA Bhaveth ||
>
> Ataeva Maheshani Gupta BhAvam MayA Kritam |
>
> ### Meaning
>
> Lord Shankara said:
>
> Jiva gets fit for liberation only after traveling through all the 84
>   lacs of yonis. Now if mahagyana is obtained by it sometime before that
>   then it will be liberated. How will it travel through all the 84 lacs
>   yonis then? Hey Devi, that's why i have said that for the purpose of
>   maintaining secrecy.

In a later verse Lord Shiva clarifies that something that is said jokingly is simply a joke and not a lie. And the same is true for something that is said for maintaining secrecy.

> GuptaBhAvArtham Yad VAkyam PariHAsArthameva Cha |
>
> Tadarthameva Tad VAkyam Na MithyA Parameswari ||
>
> ### Meaning
>
> Hey Parameswari, whatever said for maintaining secrecy or jokingly is
>   exactly that and not a lie.

In any case, Shiva Nirmalaya is granter of liberation irrespective of who is consuming it. See the following verse from the same chapter:

> PApayukto Hi ChandAlo NirmAlyam Grihyathe YadA |
>
> Tada MokshamvApnoti Shivarupi Na CAnyathA ||
>
> ### Meaning
>
> **Even if a sinful Chandala partakes my Nirmalaya he will be liberated,**
>   he will be like Shiva, & it will never happen otherwise.

All the verses are from **Sri MAtrikA Bheda Tantram's chapter 4 (or Patala 4).**

Comment: ohh..but what scriptures say jiva has to travel all 84 lakh yonis to get liberated?

Comment: @TheDestroyer I already gave the name. Its the Matrika bheda Tantram where Lord Shiva says so.

Comment: i think dharma shastras prohibit it ... but there are exceptions

Comment: @RakeshJoshi I have not found any such prohibitions  in Dharma Shastras.

Comment: http://anudinam.org/2012/05/06/to-eat-or-not-to-eat/

Comment: I think the mantras starting with Atmatatwaya etc sd end with swaha instead of namah. these are tantrik achamana mantras.please check:)

Comment: Yes the Tantric Tattva achmana uses Swaha .. but here I am quoting from Narada Purana .. not sure that it is talking about doing achaman .. it does not say to sip water with the mantra recital @Partha

Comment: @Rickross Oh i see. thanks. as its starting of tge process, i think its aachamana, and so swaha and namah bothnare permitted:)

Comment: Yes acc to Tantra women etc shd chant namah or hrim instead of swaha (vahnijaya) @Partha

Answer (score 4):

Swami Sivananda says here - http://www.dlshq.org/download/lordsiva.htm#_VPID_33 - under "Philosophy of Abhisheka", that -

> The Abhisheka water or other articles used for Abhisheka are considered very sacred and bestow immense benefits on the devotees who take it as the Lord’s Prasad. It purifies the heart and destroys countless sins. You must take it with intense Bhava and faith.