# Pouring of water on 'shivalingam'

Tags: shiva, shiva-lingam

While attend an lecture, i was told that the **shivalingam** is made up of **granite** that has radioactive counterparts of *Uranium*, *radon* and many other elements. So pouring the water on the *shivalingam* compensate the effect of radioactive compounds.

And we are not allowed to **touch**
The water after pouring on **shivalingam**

**Question**:-
Is this reason correct or it just an scientific explanation of that practice.

Thankyou
[here is the reference](https://www.epa.gov/radiation/granite-countertops-and-radiation)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can devotees drink "Abhishekam water" of Shiva Lingam?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/11165/can-devotees-drink-abhishekam-water-of-shiva-lingam)

Comment: From the link, i understood the spiritual meaning of the practice. As it refer the water as "charnamrit" , but my question is sustained as ' it can be possible explanation of abhishake ?

Comment: Just to let you know asking for scientific reasons or explanations for some religious practice is considered as off-topic here. Btw welcome to the site. @VedantChourey

Comment: Ok i will keep that in mind in future

Comment: @Rickross without relating mastras or shastra or vedas to science none can understand the essence of them.Science is what vedas teach If mere chanting of mantras has the power then why only arjuna was the one...because he knew the science behind shooting.So hinduism is real science and website should not consider it as off topic.

Comment: But on this website it is considered as off-topic .. You can see meta discussion on this and add your inputs there @PravinRGMishra

Comment: @Rickross i like your answers anyway

Comment: Thanks @PravinRGMishra nice to know that